# Is 2.5 hours enough time between domestic arrival and international departure at Stansted?

Tags: transit, short-connections, security, stn

I will be flying with Ryanair from Glasgow International to London Stansted. I will ONLY have cabin baggage. I have paid for "Priority & 2 cabin bags" on this flight to ensure I can take my baggage onboard, as I don't have much time between flights to be waiting at the baggage claim area.

My flight arrives at Stansted at 08.55 (5th April), and I have another flight departing from Stansted at 11.25 to Aarhus.

IF my inbound flight is not delayed, this gives me a maximum of 2.5 hours between flights. What is the minimum time I would need to get off the plane and go straight to security for the boarding gate? I will have checked in online in advance, and as I mentioned, will not have any baggage to check in.

I have been lucky this far and never experienced any longer than 30 minutes delayed departures with any airline. IF I allow, say, an hour for a delayed departure from Glasgow, would 1.5 hours still be sufficient time between flights at Stansted? Would it be worthwhile booking the Security Fast Track?

I have never travelled via Stansted before, so I have no idea how big or busy the airport is, or if 1.5 hours would be enough time.

Comment: I've never been to Stansted, but 2.5 hours seems like plenty to me based on my experience at much larger airports.

Comment: Assuming your incoming flight is on time, 2.5 hours should be fine. Without waiting for checked bags, an hour to get through immigration and customs is a reasonable scenario (it shouldn't be much longer than this, and should be shorter). That gives 1.5 hours to check in and go through security again.

I think the real concern is if your Ryanair flight arrives late, in which case you're out of luck.

Comment: @JoeMalt there should be no immigration or customs for a traveler arriving in Stansted from Scotland.

Answer (score 5):

2.5 hours sounds reasonably safe, given the circumstances.

Longer is better, of course.  You've booked two separate tickets, so if there is any failure of the original flight to land in Stansted with sufficient time, missing the second flight will be your problem to solve, not the airline's.  (I think you are aware of this.)

The one and only time I've done this, I booked a four-hour window just to be 100% sure (and we were connecting at Heathrow, a busier airport).  If the consequences of missing your second flight are severe, a longer connection is better, even if it means arriving the night before.